# How to remove an organization whihc is created already?

Tags: apigee

I like to remove\delete the organization from https://apigee.com/appservices/#!/organizations URL. Please let me know the steps to be performed for the same.

Comment: This is a support question for Apigee as there is no way for users to delete orgs from Apigee.

Answer (score 0):

Only Apigee can remove the Org.  You'll need to email help@apigee.com and ask them to kill it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the answer. The question should probably be removed from SO as there is no way for users to remove orgs once they have been created.